# synchronized on an Object seems like it's not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, java-threads

I  run a program which contains the following classes (not only, but these are the relevant ones for the question)

Under *Results* class I have a synchronized LinkedHashMap such as:

```
private static Map<Integer,Result>    resultsHashMap=Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Result>());
```

and a getter method:

```
public static Map<Integer,Result> getResultsHashMap() {
        return resultsHashMap;
}
```

As well I have inside my *Result* class a constructor with this synchronized code:

```
public Result(){
    synchronized (Lock.lock) {
        uniqueIdResult++;
    }
}
```

and a synchronized getter method as such:

```
public static int getUniqueIdResult() {
    synchronized (Lock.lock) {
        return uniqueIdResult;
    }

}
```

the uniqueIdResult is defined as following:

```
private static int uniqueIdResult=0;
```

Also I have a Lock class consists this Object:

```
public static final Lock lock=new Lock();
```

Now, this is the important issue i'm after. In my program I have the next 2 lines, which are creating a Result and putting it into the HashMap

```
Result result = new Result();
Results.getResultsHashMap().put(Result.getUniqueIdResult(), result);
```

I try to run my program with different number of Threads. When it is being run with 1 thread the output is as I expect it to be (specifically, but not necessarily important, Results.resultsHashMap contains 433 keys, which is what should be, and the keys are starting from 1).

But when I run it with different number of Threads, it gives a different output. For example  running with 6 Threads gives a different number of keys each time, sometimes 430, sometimes 428, sometimes 427, etc.. and the starting key is not always related to the total number of keys (e.g total_number_of_keys-starting_key_number+1, which seemed to me in the beginning to be some pattern, but realized it's not)

The iteration is like this:

```
int counterOfResults=0;
    for (Integer key : Results.getResultsHashMap().keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " " + Results.getResultsHashMap().get(key));
        counterOfResults++;
    }
    System.out.println(counterOfResults);
```

Also when *synchronizing the getter method for getting the hashMap*, without synchronization of the Result creation and the insertion to the hashMap, the output with multiple threads gives wrong output.
Also, *when synchronizing only one of the lines* (creation of Result and putting into hashMap), the output is not coherent under multiple Threads.

However when I synchronize **both** these lines (the creation of Result and putting into the map) like so:

```
Result result;
    synchronized (Lock.lock) {
         result = new Result(currentLineTimeNationalityNameYearofbirth.getName(),currentLineTimeNationalityNameYearofbirth.getTime(),citycompetionwas,date,distance,stroke,gender,kindofpool);
        Results.getResultsHashMap().put(Result.getUniqueIdResult(), result);
    }
```

the output is perfect, no matter how many Threads I use.

Also, I will note that the output is being printed only after all Threads have finished, by using *join* method for all Threads created.

**So my question is:**
As far as I know, before synchronizing the 2 lines (creating Result and puting into hashMap) all of my **critical sections** ,e.g, changing and getting the *uniqueIdResult*, getting the *resultsHashMap* (as I mentioned, I tried synchronizing this getter method also)  are being synchronized on the same object, plus I put a further safe approach when puting the hashMap with Collections.synchronizedMap, which,as far as I know, should make the hashMap thread-safe.

Why then the output is not as I expect it to be? Where is there a safety problem?

Comment: "starting from 4 (at least when I checked)" what does this mean? It sounds like you're not sure which number it started at. Please provide reproducible code.

Comment: I meant, that in the times that I ran the program on 4 threads (about 10 times), this was the output. Since the output is not always coherent (and with 6 threads I noticed different outputs on different executions), I assume it could have also been a different number. Anyway I removed this part from my question, since it might be unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no exclusion around these lines:

```
Result result = new Result();
Results.getResultsHashMap().put(Result.getUniqueIdResult(), result);
```

If you have 4 threads, they might all execute the first line (which will increment the `uniqueIdResult` variable four times), and then all execute the second line (at which point they will all see the same return value from `getUniqueIdResult()`). That explains how your keys could start at 4 when you have 4 (or more) threads.

Because you have multiple threads potentially (and unpredictably) storing to the same key, you also end up with a variable number of entries in your map.

You should probably remove the increment from the `Result` class constructor and instead do it in the `getUniqueIdResult` method:

```
public static int getUniqueIdResult() {
    synchronized (Lock.lock) {
        return ++uniqueIdResult;
    }
}
```

(Having done that, there is no longer any need to create instances of `Result` at all).